# What happens when using this sequence of bitwise operators

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

i came across this function in javascript

```
function(x) {
    return (x >> 8 << 8) ^ x;
};
```

it is used to convert an x to a byte representation. I understand what the bitwise operations do, however i don't understand what happens, as (122 >> 8 << 8) prints out 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x >> 8
```

This right shifts x 8 times, effectively clearing the least significant 8 bits.

```
(x >> 8) << 8
```

This left shifts the above quantity by 8 bits. Thus, we get x, with the least significant 8 bits set to 0.
If x (16 bit number) was initially 0b0001000101010101, it first becomes 0b0000000000010001, and finally becomes 0b0001000100000000.

```
(x >> 8 << 8) ^ x
```

This will xor the above number with x, leaving the least significant 8 bits intact and clearing all the rest to 0.
Thus, the least significant byte is obtained.
It will work in your case as well, since 122 is less than 2^8. Xoring 122 with 0 returns the least significant byte - 122 itself.